# tkinter: Created image doesn't appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on creating a card game in python. I would like to create a function which displays a picture in a tkinter window, but no image appears. I have all the picture files in the right place.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

pictures = ['1C kopiera.gif', '1D kopiera.gif', '1H kopiera.gif', '1S kopiera.gif',
            '2C kopiera. gif', '2D kopiera.gif', '2H kopiera.gif', '2S kopiera.gif',
            '3C kopiera.gif','3D kopiera.gif', '3H kopiera.gif', '3S kopiera.gif',
            '4C kopiera.gif', '4D kopiera.gif', '4H kopiera.gif', '4S kopiera.gif',
            '5C kopiera.gif', '5D kopiera.gif', '5H kopiera.gif', '5S kopiera.gif',
            '6C kopiera.gif', '6D kopiera.gif', '6H kopiera.gif', '6S kopiera.gif',
            '7C kopiera.gif', '7D kopiera.gif', '7H kopiera.gif', '7S kopiera.gif',
            '8C kopiera.gif', '8D kopiera.gif', '8H kopiera.gif', '8S kopiera.gif',
            '9C kopiera.gif', '9D kopiera.gif', '9H kopiera.gif', '9S kopiera.gif',
            '10C kopiera.gif', '10D kopiera.gif', '10H kopiera.gif',
            '10S kopiera.gif', '11C kopiera.gif', '11D kopiera.gif',
            '11S kopiera.gif', '11h kopiera.gif', '12C kopiera.gif',
            '12D kopiera.gif', '12H kopiera.gif', '12S kopiera.gif',
            '13C kopiera.gif', '13D kopiera.gif', '13H kopiera.gif',
            '13S kopiera.gif']

C = Canvas(root, width=1300, height=750, bg="dark green")
C.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=20)
root.title("Black Jack")

def create_image():
    gif = PhotoImage(file=""
                     + "/Users/ivanwahlund/PycharmProjects/yeboi/5C kopiera.gif")
    C.create_image(400, 350, image=gif)

create_image()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is that a typo in `PhotoImage(.....boi/"5C kopiera.gif")`?

Comment: no it does however work outside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gif object is a local variable.
Make it **global** and the image will display.

Usually you should save a reference to the image.

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

pictures =['1C kopiera.gif', '1D kopiera.gif', '1H kopiera.gif', '1S kopiera.gif', '2C kopiera. gif', '2D kopiera.gif', '2H kopiera.gif', '2S kopiera.gif', '3C kopiera.gif','3D kopiera.gif', '3H kopiera.gif', '3S kopiera.gif', '4C kopiera.gif', '4D kopiera.gif', '4H kopiera.gif', '4S kopiera.gif', '5C kopiera.gif', '5D kopiera.gif', '5H kopiera.gif', '5S kopiera.gif', '6C kopiera.gif', '6D kopiera.gif', '6H kopiera.gif', '6S kopiera.gif', '7C kopiera.gif', '7D kopiera.gif', '7H kopiera.gif', '7S kopiera.gif', '8C kopiera.gif', '8D kopiera.gif', '8H kopiera.gif', '8S kopiera.gif', '9C kopiera.gif', '9D kopiera.gif', '9H kopiera.gif', '9S kopiera.gif','10C kopiera.gif', '10D kopiera.gif', '10H kopiera.gif', '10S kopiera.gif', '11C kopiera.gif', '11D kopiera.gif', '11S kopiera.gif', '11h kopiera.gif', '12C kopiera.gif', '12D kopiera.gif', '12H kopiera.gif', '12S kopiera.gif', '13C kopiera.gif', '13D kopiera.gif', '13H kopiera.gif', '13S kopiera.gif']



C = Canvas(root, width=1300, height=750, bg="dark green")

C.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=20)
root.title("Black Jack")

def create_image():
    global gif    # make it global else out of scope
    gif = PhotoImage(file="earth.gif")
    C.create_image(400, 350, image=gif)
    C.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=20)

create_image()
root.mainloop()
```